# Android: ListView adding Items on scroll

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am getting data from server in a `listview` using a custom `adapter`. The data coming from server is a large amount having images with text. Now I need to load the data each time only 10 items and when I scroll down it should load more 10 items and so on. Her is how I am setting adapter code. I don't understand now how to handle this situation inside the onscroll method. I am loading all items from server at once and assigning to an arraylist. So inside onscroll method what should I do, please help me with some code.

```
list = (ArrayList<ListItems>) control.Table.GetData();

        final ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.user_data);

        adapter = new customAdapter(this, list);
        adapter.setLayout(this, layout);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        listview.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

               final int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
               if(lastItem == totalItemCount) {
                   //Here I have to add next 10 items from arraylist

               }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried lazyLoad. because that seems appropriate option

Comment: Yes I am using lazy adapter

Comment: So if you load try to scroll to bottom but data from server has not been parsed yet. what problems did you face that time lagging or forseclose??

Comment: Data is loading correctly but the problem I am facing is when I scroll down the os shows e the message of app not responding with a choice of `wait` or `close` and this is due to the images that loading slowly .

Comment: May be you can use flashScreen until the data done loding. If data from server are finite.

Comment: Yes that would be nice. But what do you say, if to add a button at the footer and implement onScroll method?

Comment: That seems complicated.FlashScreen might not work at that time. Or may be you can show little Toast if data has not been parse yet and you try to access bottom part of the screen that `wait until data loading completed`.

Comment: And I think a toast showing for some time will be a best option

Comment: Yeah that's right this might help. but your question becomes difficult if numbers of rows in list are not fixed i.e. Infinite or indefinite number of data.

Comment: Yeah the no. of rows indefinite and by scrolling fast the app just going crash.

Comment: r u fetching all the records to arraylist at once or ur doing pagination?

Comment: no pagination just fetching all records to arraylist

Comment: @user3294034 i suggest you to use pagination. it will be more easy. if u don't want  to use pagination, i will try to solve this problem if i succeed then i will get back to u....

Comment: Ok thanks a lot i wil wait for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think large amount of text and images in a listview will be handle by android, I remember in a video Google I/O that even a million rows in a listview, android can handle hit. just implement the best practice on how to manage views/rows in a listview just to avoid recreating the rows everytime  it will be viewed.